# Problem to connect to Kafka Cluster via Jumphost on Azure

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm struggling with this problem.
I'm trying to connect into a kafka cluster via jumphost connection:
For that I'm using az cli + ssh:

```
az ssh vm -n jumphost -g PROD-HUB -- -vvv -L 9093:kafka.dev:9093
```

I read somewhere that I should map the same name of the kafka host to my localhost in `/etc/hosts.conf`

```
127.0.0.1   kafka.dev
```

The connection above works perfectly and I'm able to connect in the forwarded port:

```
curl -v telnet://kafka.dev:9093
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:9093...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to kafka.dev (127.0.0.1) port 9093 (#0)
```

I configured  the listeners and advertised.listeners this way below:

```
listeners=INTERNAL://kafka.dev:9093
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://kafka.dev:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
```

But when I tried to connect via [kafkacat](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/app-development/kafkacat-usage.html) using the command below to debug:

```
kafkacat -L -b kafka.dev:9093 -d broker
```

I receive the error:

```
%7|1660324800.333|BROKER|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap: Added new broker with NodeId -1
%7|1660324800.333|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Enter main broker thread
%7|1660324800.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap: Selected for cluster connection: bootstrap servers added (broker has 0 connection attempt(s))
%7|1660324800.333|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap]: kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap: Enter main broker thread
%7|1660324800.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap]: kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap: Received CONNECT op
%7|1660324800.333|INIT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: librdkafka v1.2.1 (0x10201ff) rdkafka#producer-1 initialized (builtin.features gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins,sasl_oauthbearer, GCC GXX INSTALL GNULD LDS C11THREADS LIBDL PLUGINS ZLIB SSL SASL_CYRUS HDRHISTOGRAM LZ4_EXT SNAPPY SOCKEM SASL_SCRAM SASL_OAUTHBEARER CRC32C_HW, debug 0x2)
%7|1660324800.333|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap]: kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
%7|1660324800.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap]: kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap: broker in state TRY_CONNECT connecting
%7|1660324800.333|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap]: kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap: Broker changed state TRY_CONNECT -> CONNECT
%7|1660324800.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1660324800.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1660324800.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1660324800.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1660324800.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap]: kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap: Connecting to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9093 (plaintext) with socket 7
%7|1660324800.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap]: kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap: Connected to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9093
%7|1660324800.333|CONNECTED|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap]: kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap: Connected (#1)
%7|1660324800.333|FEATURE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap]: kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap: Updated enabled protocol features +ApiVersion to ApiVersion
%7|1660324800.333|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap]: kafka.dev:9093/bootstrap: Broker changed state CONNECT -> APIVERSION_QUERY
%7|1660324800.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1660324800.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1660324801.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Cluster connection already in progress: no cluster connection
^C%7|1660324802.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Cluster connection already in progress: no cluster connection
^C^C%7|1660324803.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Cluster connection already in progress: no cluster connection
%7|1660324804.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Cluster connection already in progress: no cluster connection
%7|1660324805.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Cluster connection already in progress: no cluster connection
%7|1660324805.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
%7|1660324805.333|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
% ERROR: Failed to acquire metadata: Local: Broker transport failure
```

I would love to receive some help on this topic.
I'm struggling on that already for 2 days :)

Answer (score 0):

For the shown configuration, Kafka will need to be running on the jump host itself.

This way, your `/etc/hosts` points to `127.0.0.1` for the `kafka.dev` DNS name, which matches the `advertised.listeners`. When a Kafka client resolves `kafka.dev`, it'll point to the local machine, not any external Kafka cluster running elsewhere in Azure.

In general, it is difficult to connect to Kafka via a proxy / "jump host" as [clients must connect to individual brokers, and must be resolvable by any client via the configured `advertised.listeners` setting](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/). And, no, editing `/etc/hosts` should be avoided since Kafka doesn't require any DNS name configuration.

If you wanted to SSH Proxy a Kafka connection, you would need all the brokers to advertise the proxied SSH port, which does not need to match any port in the bound `listeners` config, however, if you have set a port in `advertised.listeners` that is not in the `listeners`, then the server will deny any connections on the advertised port since there is no open server port for it (only configured by `listeners`).

All in all, it might be easier for you to configure Azure EventHubs, for example, then setup network policies to not require a jump box at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and help, OneCricketeer.
I'll evaluate the possibility of using Eventhubs, and then when I'm ready, I can come back here and comment on the results. ;)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-for-kafka-ecosystem-overview